How to Conditionally Configure NestJS Module with One Default Service and Switch to Another Based on a Parameter?
I'm working on a NestJS application where I need to conditionally switch between two services within a module. One service should be set as the default, and based on a parameter, the application should be able to use the other service instead.
Problem:

I want a module to automatically use one service by default when imported, and allow switching to another service based on a parameter.
Currently, I am using a dynamic module to configure the services, but I'm facing challenges when trying to avoid explicitly configuring the module every time it is imported.
Additionally, I want to make this work without using the @Global() decorator, as it causes issues with dependency resolution.

Goal:
I want the module to:

Use one service by default when imported.
Allow switching to the second service based on a parameter passed during the module import.

Current Code:

    @Module({})
    export class MyModule {
      static register(options: { useSecondService?: boolean } = {}): DynamicModule {
        const useSecondService = options.useSecondService || false;
    
        return {
          module: MyModule,
          providers: [
            {
              provide: 'MY_SERVICE',
              useFactory: () => {
                if (useSecondService) {
                  return new SecondService();
                }
                return new FirstService();
              },
            },
          ],
          exports: ['MY_SERVICE'],
        };
      }
    
      static forRoot(): DynamicModule {
        return this.register({ useSecondService: false });
      }
    
      static forSecondService(): DynamicModule {
        return this.register({ useSecondService: true });
      }
    }


What I've Tried:
I attempted using @Global() to make the module available globally, but it caused dependency resolution issues in other modules.
I tried importing the module like imports: [MyModule] but got error.
imports: [MyModule.register({ useSecondService: false })] works, but I want it to work as imports: [MyModule] and it should use default config.
 [Nest] 14264  - 12/19/2024, 11:55:31 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserProfileService (ProfileRepository, UserRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument "IMAGE_UPLOAD_SERVICE" at index [2] is available in the UsersModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is UsersModule a valid NestJS module?
- If "IMAGE_UPLOAD_SERVICE" is a provider, is it part of the current UsersModule?
- If "IMAGE_UPLOAD_SERVICE" is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UsersModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing "IMAGE_UPLOAD_SERVICE" */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserProfileService (ProfileRepository, UserRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument "IMAGE_UPLOAD_SERVICE" at index [2] is available in the UsersModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is UsersModule a valid NestJS module?
- If "IMAGE_UPLOAD_SERVICE" is a provider, is it part of the current UsersModule?
- If "IMAGE_UPLOAD_SERVICE" is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UsersModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing "IMAGE_UPLOAD_SERVICE" */ ]
  })

    at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (C:\server\gateway\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:254:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Injector.resolveComponentInstance (C:\server\gateway\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:207:33)
    at resolveParam (C:\server\gateway\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:128:38)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (C:\server\gateway\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:143:27)
    at Injector.loadInstance (C:\server\gateway\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:70:13)
    at Injector.loadProvider (C:\server\gateway\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:97:9)
    at C:\server\gateway\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:56:13
    at async Promise.all (index 4)

What I Need Help With:
How can I set one service as the default without needing any explicit configuration each time the module is imported?

do you need to use a service as default in a module without calling method like MyModule.forRoot() ?
